# Определить расширение файла

Tags: android

Помогите понять, как при переборе файлов разобрать - что есть музыка, картинка, а что - текстовый файл?

Comment: если опустить несоответствие расширения с типом файла, то можно просто проверять расширение файла. У `File` есть метод `getName` возвращающий имя файла вместе с расширением. Берете его, обрезая все после последней точки и пускаете в `switch`

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = ...;
String name = file.getName();
String ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
switch (ext) {
    case "apk": 
        //это android приложение
        break;
    case "png" :
    case "jpg":
    case "jpeg":
        //это картинка
        break;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)))))))))

Comment: Лучше ``switch (ext.toLowerCase())``. А то всякое бывает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, еще может быть что отстутствует расширение.

Comment: если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его (зеленая галочка слева)